# What happened in this edit log?

Tags: discussion, editing

[This question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/9688/revisions) received two edits by user T G. Those edits made no improvements to the answer.

Why did these edits go through? Should I revert them?

Possibly related, this user (T G) seems to own the domain that this answer links to via URL (based on the image in the top right corner of that site).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TG's edit description explains that he is rebranding. Common rebranding tactics include leaving the old website up for 72 hours or longer (so that the bots have time to fetch your new site). After some time has passed, it is possible that the old website will cease to exist, at which point the usefulness of TG's edit will become clear: he preemptively saved us from link rot.

It is also possible that TG is not who he says he is, in which case his edit is probably useless.

I think that we should trust that TG's edit description is accurate and leave it alone. If the new link rots, then we can fix it later.

Comment: Thanks! I was worried that maybe this new site didn't belong to the same person as the old one, and this was a way of stealing traffic. Didn't see the rebranding explanation.